# Using Array.map() in conjuction with parseInt gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, arrays, parseint

I have the following JS Problem.
If i try to convert an array of strings using the parseInt function as a mapped function with the Array.map method, i experienced this strange result. What is wrong here?

```
console.log(['1','1'].map(parseInt))
```

Returns a strange Array containing the following:

`[1, NaN]`

Is parseInt not a regular function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, `parseInt` is not a regular function. It takes 2 arguments. The first is the number to parse, the second is the radix. `Array.map` passes 3 - the value, index, and full array.

Each call goes like this:

```
 parseInt('1', 0) // 1
 parseInt('1', 1) // NaN
```

To fix this, you need to manually call the function.

```
console.log(['1','1'].map(function(num){
    return parseInt(num);
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

`parseInt` takes multiple parameters. `Array.map` is run with multiple parameters.

to avoid side effects, you can run it like this:

```
console.log(['1','1'].map(function(item){
    return parseInt(item);
}))
```

Comment: ...and it's even readable IMHO